Avoid VSCode remote SSH session disconnection when there is no mouse activity
I have windows 11 Laptop with a vscode installed on it. I am using Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extencsion for SSHing to linux remote server.
I am executing (through vscode itegrated terminal) scripts on the linux server that could take hours to complete.
Before launching the script,
I have changed power plan settings on windows, and make my Laptop not to sleep ever when it's connected to power. Also, I have increased the SSH timeout in vscode ssh settings to maximum.
Unfortunatley, when leaving (no mouse activity) the computer for a while (few minutes its sufecient), vscode disconnects from the remote server and closes the remote ssh sessions, and reload/reconnect to the remote server is needed.
How to solve this issue and prevent vscode disconnecting from the remote server ?
I came across few solutions here and there that says that it's related to windows background activity, such as preventing Windows from suspending USB devices, which can affect network adapters (via advanced power plan settings), Or installing third-Party tool: "Coffee" which simulates mouse movement.
